Why can't SOL be sent out of a mint address using "solana transfer" in the CLI?
From https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues/2134 :
Create a new fungible mint. Send some SOL to the mint address (and be prepared to lose it!). You can't use "solana transfer" to retrieve it, regardless of what fee payer account you specify. Is this somehow illegal under the protocol? If so, then it would be nice to have a warning somewhere in the docs, or in real time "I noticed you're trying to fund a mint address, which is a black hole..."

In Solana, programs own accounts, and only the owning program can deduct SOL from its accounts. solana transfer can't know how every program on Solana works, and whether a destination is or isn't a black hole. For example, mints on SPL Token can't recover extra SOL, but it's possible to recover them from token accounts, and it's possible with mints on SPL Token 2022.
Perhaps we can add a protection flag in the CLI like --require-destination-owned-by-system-program for users that are worried about sending tokens to non-wallet destinations.
You can learn more about the Solana account model at https://solana.com/docs/core/accounts#key-points

"mints on SPL Token can't recover extra SOL, but it's possible to recover them from token accounts" The first part is the answer I was looking for. But in the second part, I assume you mean that it's possible to recover rent by burning a token account (because SOL isn't stored in a token account). Yes it would help to have a protective CLI option like you mentioned, ideally enabled by default.
